# Send variable together with message in camunda

Tags: java, camunda

I have a receiving process which has an intermediate message event waiting for a message send by a sending process.

I am already able to trigger the intermediate message event by the following delegate code in my sending process:

```
RuntimeService runtimeService = ProcessEngines
        .getDefaultProcessEngine()
        .getRuntimeService();
MessageCorrelationResult result = runtimeService
        .createMessageCorrelation("my-message-name")
        .setVariable("customer", customer)    //trigger instance where customer matches
        .correlateWithResult();
```

My question is: **How can I send a variable from the sending process to the receiving process combined with the message? Are there any best practices?**

This is what I haved tried so far:

```
// Set the variable after the correlation
runtimeService.setVariable(result.getProcessInstance().getId(),
    "variableToSend", variableToSend);
```

I try to retrieve the variable in a `JavaDelegate` like this:

```
// Access the sent variable
Double sendByOtherProcess = (Double) delegate.getVariable("variableToSend");
// sendByOtherProcess == null
```

Interestingly enough, it is possible to retrieve `variableToSend` in an embedded form via JavaScript in the receiving process.

I read that it might be an isse due to synchron/asynchron behavior?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You already did it with .setVariable on the MessageCorrelationBuilder. https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.7/org/camunda/bpm/engine/runtime/MessageCorrelationBuilder.html

Comment: Yes, thank you! I interchanged `.setVariable` with `.processInstanceVariableEquals`. If you file an answer I'll accept it. And I'll promise to read the documentation carefully next time ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had already set a variable on the MessageCorrelationBuilder, with `MessageCorrelationBuilder#setVariable`. For more information see the JavaDoc or the [MessageCorrelationBuilder](https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.7/org/camunda/bpm/engine/runtime/MessageCorrelationBuilder.html)

As you mentioned you want to correlate the message to a process which matches with the given variable. For that you have to use the `#processInstanceVariableEquals` method.